# How do I create multiple instances of a struct using a function?

Tags: c

I need to create unique instances of a struct and return its address without using malloc.

The problem is everytime I call the function that creates the struct instance, the address to the instance is the same.

inside of List.h

```
typedef struct List_s List;
struct List_s{
    Node* next; 
};
```

inside of List.c

```
List* List_Create(){
    static List head; 

    printf("%p\n", &head); <--- In both function calls prints out the same address

    return NULL; 
}


int main(void){

    List_Create(); 
    List_Create(); // I  

}
```

I have tried not using the static keyword but the same problem occurs. Additionally, I have put initialized the List struct outside of the function and no problem occurs, but I need to do it inside of a function.

Comment: You need dynamic allocation

Comment: `return malloc(sizeof List);`

Comment: I need to do this without using malloc

Comment: @sam Then you're out of luck.

Comment: Do you have to return a pointer? You could just return a `List` instead of `List*`. Then it's the caller's job to create unique instances that it assigns when calling the function.

Comment: You can't create an arbitrary number of objects (which is decided in the runtime) without using some kind of dynamic allocation. If you know the number beforehand, then it's a different story, but you should tell us about it.

Comment: @Barmar yes I have to return the pointer

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know the number beforehand

Comment: Then you can create a static array of `List` objects, and return the address of one of the array elements.

Comment: Use a static index variable to remember which ones have been returned, then return the next one on each call.

Comment: @Barmar Things will get a bit more complicated if deleting nodes is required too :)

Comment: does `realloc(0, sizeof(List))` count as `malloc`?

Comment: ...or maybe calloc()?  Static anything needs to be clearly docomented 'no recursion, no multithreading':(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very simple implementation that uses a fixed-size static array, and returns a pointer to an element of it.

```
List* List_Create(){
    static List lists[MAX_LISTS];
    static int index = 0;

    if (index >= MAX_LISTS) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // initialze contents of lists[index] here
    return &lists[index++];
}
```

If you also need to be able to destroy lists to the pool you'll need to make `lists` a global variable, so it can be used by both `List_Create` and `List_Destroy`. And you'll need some way of keeping track of which elements have been destroyed. You could wrap each `List` in another struct that has an `in_use` member.

Answer (score 2):

By using `static`, there is only one instance, with lifetime for the duration of the process.

Without `static` you are creating an instance with lifetime for the duration of that specific call.  Returning an pointer to that instance us invalid, it's memory is available for reuse.

To do that without heap allocation would require a pool of instances.  For example:

```
#define MAX_LISTS 200 

List* List_Create( void )
{
    static List list_pool[MAX_LISTS] ;
    static size_t next_list = 0 ;

    List* list = NULL ;
    if( next_list < MAX_LISTS )
    {
        list = &list_pool[next_list] ; 
    }

    return list ; 
}
```

The above is a very crude example, it has no means of returning list to the pool, which may be a requirement.  To do that you would need to move the `static`s outside of the function and have a means of marking an element used/unused, and a means of searching for an unused element on "creation".  However the point is that you need a pool, the precise implementation is beyond the scope of this question I think.